# Advanced Calculator

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I have a calculator with this code at the end:

'Code for when more than 3 digits are pressed'

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 Then
        MsgBox("You can't add any more numbers!")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Remove(TextBox1.Text.Length - 1, 1)
```

But when I do a sum on the calculator the textbox is still limited to the digits so all the answers are 3 digits long.

How do I change the code so it limits the textbox when entering digits but not when answering a sum?

Answer (score 0):

You can use e.Cancel = True

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged


    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 Then
        MsgBox("You can't add any more numbers!")
        e.Cancel = True
```

Comment: it isnt part of System.EventArgs

Answer (score 0):

Take a boolean variable 'IsModifiedByUser' at form level. By default, it should be true. When you are programmetically modifying the textbox, set value of IsModifiedByUser as false before that. After you have modified textbox programmetically, again set the value of IsModifiedByUser as true. Check the length of textbox value only if IsModifiedByUser is true.

```
Private IsModifiedByUser As Boolean = True

Protected Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If TextBox1.Text.Length > 3 AndAlso IsModifiedByUser Then
        MsgBox("You can't add any more numbers!")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub

Public Sub CalculateValue()
    IsModifiedByUser = False
    'Do the calculation and set the value in textbox
    IsModifiedByUser = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I am a very very amatuer programmer, i dont know what you are talking about=